# Convert to conjunctive normal form (for Gentzen-Formulae)

Tags: logic, conjunctive-normal-form

unfortunately I don't quite get how I should reach Step 2 with the Distributive Laws and I'm getting also confused how it is allowed to put the OR's in Step 1 in brackets.

[Task & Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl0pM.png)

The result I'm getting in Step 1 looks like this:

(¬R ⋁ (S ⋁ (¬Q ⋀ P ))) ⋀ ((¬S ⋀ (Q ⋁ ¬P)) ⋁ R)

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please edit your question to include the task and solution in MathJax form, this is relevant for future users to be able to consult this question rather than asking it again. Also, is good practice in general to put the question in your own words..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the right hand side of the original formula is $S \lor \neg Q \land P$, and it is not clear how to read that. Is that to be interpreted as:

$S \lor (\neg Q \land P)$  (this is how you interpreted it as)

or as:

$(S \lor \neg Q) \land P$ (this is what the answer key did)

These two way statements are not equivalent, and so that's why you go a different answer.

Now, because of this, most logic textbooks will simply not accept any statement of the form $P \lor Q \land R$, and force you to place parentheses to disambiguate.  However, a few textbooks have some kind of priority scheme to disambiguate, so that's what may be happening here.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that AND has normally a higher priority than OR, this is also stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective
So how should I deal with it? EDIT: If I remember correctly this is also the way I learned this.

Comment: @Leschge It all depends on the textbook; there is really no universal standard on this. So, you should deal with it by referring to the textbook that this problem appears in (or that your instroctor is using).  Personally, I always use parentheses: then there is never any issue at all. And this is what most textbooks as well.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just called a friend of mine that says the same thing. In all other tasks we have to use the priority given above. In this one there are no just like you said.